# Azure Pipeline -- Authenticate once to Azure for all subsequent steps

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-cli, azure-pipelines-yaml

### Problem

In an Azure DevOps (ADO) pipeline, I need to run 5+ bash steps that each require authentication to Azure.

I want to authenticate once in the first step, and have the cached token be available for all downstream steps.

I already have a service-principal-backed Azure Resource Manager service connection ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAF7s.png)).

### Redundant Workarounds

Both of the workarounds below seem redundant because the ARM service connection already has the service principal connection. Moreover, our org will auto-rotate SP secrets every 6 months, so the fewer places to have to update the new SP secret, the better.

#### Secret Pipeline Variables

[This pipeline](https://gist.github.com/swanderz/d34ae0935f2b8439f337460e595019ae#file-use_pipeline_vars-yml) works if I duplicate the SP creds as manually-created secret Pipeline variables.

#### Get SP creds from Key Vault

[This pipeline](https://gist.github.com/swanderz/d34ae0935f2b8439f337460e595019ae#file-use_key_vault-yml) is also redundant as I'm using the the ARM Service connection (which has the SP creds) to connect to a Key Vault, to fetch the SP creds. But it works so, `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

### Additional Context

I'm using `dbt` and `dbt-sqlserver` package, which makes use of the `azure-identity` Python package to authenticate to an Azure SQL database (db).

This seems somewhat related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64502148/how-to-securely-login-in-az-cli-from-a-devops-pipeline)

Answer (score 1):

In the Azure CLI task, we do not need to use the az login cli. And since you have the existing service principal, we recommend you can create an Azure Resource Manager service connection by using the manually and use this new service connection in the Azure CLI task.
You can refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/connect-to-azure?view=azure-devops#create-an-azure-resource-manager-service-connection-with-an-existing-service-principal).

Comment: thanks for jumping in to help! I already have an ARM Service connection. Are you saying that I need an Azure CLI task for every single step that requires Azure authentication? There must be a simpler way...

Comment: In the Azure CLI task, we do not need the azure authentication, we can use the service connection to help us. As we can know, we can use different ARM connection in different Azure CLI tasks. This might be the simpler way.

Comment: I’ve spent multiple hours writing and editing my question to make it clear. Can you please read my question again?

Answer (score 1):

Check this blog out: https://www.integration-playbook.io/docs/combining-az-cli-and-azure-powershell-az-modules-in-a-pipeline

Basically you have to add 2 tasks:

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: Expose SP credentials as env variables
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: <YOUR SUBSCRIPTION>
    scriptType: bash
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: |
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_ID;]$servicePrincipalId"
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_KEY;]$servicePrincipalKey"
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=TENANT_ID;]$tenantId"
    addSpnToEnvironment: true

- script: |
    az login --service-principal --username  $SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_ID --password $SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_KEY --tenant $TENANT_ID
  displayName: Login to Azure
```

In first one you store credentials as evn variables thanks to *addSpnToEnvironment* parameter. And in second one you use them to login to azure.

In all following tasks you don't have to log in again and can use already logged in account like this:

```
- script: az account show
```

Comment: interesting approach, I think this would work! I have to try it out first though. My only hangup is that the `AzureCLI` task does log in for you automatically, so the second task of `az login` seems redundant. But, this might be the only way to do it as the `AzureCLI` task must clean up and log out at the end of each task.

Comment: Yes, user is logged out at end of the task:
https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/6ca4943e08700be8441dcd9f0a1ce56ba9f9b52d/Tasks/AzureCLIV2/azureclitask.ts#L95