# ERROR: The requested resource requires user authentication: https://dev.azure.com/my_org/my_project/_apis/git/repositories

Tags: azure-devops, azure-cli, azure-repos

I am logging into az cli using correct token:
`echo my_pat | az devops login`

But I see the following error while getting the existing repositories in a project:

`az repos list --org {ado_org_url} --project {ado_project} --query '[*].name'`

**ERROR: The requested resource requires user authentication: [https://dev.azure.com/my_org/my_project/\_apis/git/repositories](https://dev.azure.com/my_org/my_project/%5C_apis/git/repositories)**

Am I missing any settings while setting up my pat? How can I get rid of this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to use the **az devops login** if you already set an **AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT** Environment Variable. If you not set an **AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT** Environment Variable set it first and do your CLI Task.

**The `az devops` commands now enable sign-in with `az login`, you don't need to give a token if you've already signed in with `az login` interactively or with a username and password. However, you can't use `az login` to log in as the service principal. A PAT is required in that case.**

If you still need to **log in** by using **az devops login** it requires the ***User Authentication***.  For that, you have to **login** using Service Principle

```json
 "user": {
    "name": "***",
    "type": "servicePrincipal"
  }
```

#### References

- [How to securely login in Az CLI from a DevOps Pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64502183/15997690)
- [Fix ERROR: The requested resource requires User Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68334641/15997690)
- [MSDOC for Azure DevOps CLI sign in with a PAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/cli/log-in-via-pat?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows)

Comment: Thank you. Setting the environment variable instead of using 'az devops login' helped get rid of this error.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the authentication error you encountered while running the Azure CLI command, ensure that your Personal Access Token (PAT) includes the following permissions:

Build:
Artifacts, definitions, requests, queue a build and update build properties
Permission: Read

Code:
Source code, repositories, pull requests, and notifications
Permission: Read

Pipeline Resources:
Manage a pipeline run's access to pipeline resources
Permission: Use

Release:
Read, update, and delete releases, release pipelines, and stages
Permission: Read

Once you've confirmed that your PAT has these permissions, you can use the Azure CLI command successfully. Make sure to regenerate your PAT if needed and update your Azure DevOps CLI configuration to use the new token.

Here's an example of how you can regenerate your PAT:

Go to your Azure DevOps organization settings.
Navigate to the Personal Access Tokens page.
Generate a new token with the required permissions listed above.
Update your Azure DevOps CLI configuration to use the new token.
After updating your PAT and configuring the Azure DevOps CLI, you should be able to run the az repos list command without encountering authentication errors.